# R Shiny does not plot the bar plot on dialogue box

Tags: r, shiny, bar-chart, shinyapps

I am trying to add a bar plot on the dialogue box in my shiny app.And I am not succeeding.  I am have inspired by this shiny app (https://shiny.rstudio.com/gallery/superzip-example.html), where the histogram appears on the dialogue box and it is updating itself when moving on different zip code. And was hoping to achieve something similar yet not succeeding.

The code I am using for my shiny app is this:

```
library(shiny)
library(tidyverse)
library(leaflet.extras)
library(leaflet)
library(RColorBrewer)
library(scales)
library(lattice)
library(dplyr)


fake_data <- read_csv("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/gabrielburcea/stackoverflow_fake_data/master/gather_divided.csv")

min_date <- as.Date("2020-04-09", "%Y-%m-%d")
max_date <- as.Date("2020-05-06",, "%Y-%m-%d")

plot_freq_country <- function(data, start_date = min_date, 
                              end_date = max_date, 
                              title = "Frequency accross Symptoms"){
  
 
  
  plot <- ggplot2::ggplot(fake_data, ggplot2::aes(x = Symptom, y = n, fill = n)) +
    ggplot2::coord_flip() +
    ggplot2::geom_bar(stat = "identity", position = "dodge") +
    ggplot2::scale_fill_viridis_c(option = "magma", direction = -1) +
    ggplot2::scale_x_discrete(limits = unique(fake_data$Symptom)) +
    #ggplot2::theme(legend.position = "bottom") +
    #ggplot2::guides(fill = ggplot2::guide_legend(nrow = 3)) +
    ggplot2::theme_minimal()
  
  plotly::ggplotly(plot)  
  
  
}



# Define UI for application that draws a histogram
ui <- bootstrapPage(
    
    navbarPage(theme = shinytheme("flatly"), header = "", 
               "Symptom Tracker", id = "nav",
                 
                 tabPanel("Interactive map", 
                          div(class = "outer",
                              tags$head(includeCSS("styles.css")),
                              
                              #tags$head(tags$link(rel = "stylesheet", type = "text/css", href = "style.css")),
                              
                              leafletOutput("map", width = "100%", height = 1000), 
                             
                              tags$style(type = "text/css", ".container-fluid {padding-left:0px;padding-right:0px;}"),
                              tags$style(type = "text/css", ".navbar {margin-bottom: .5px;}"),
                              tags$style(type = "text/css", ".container-fluid .navbar-header .navbar-brand {margin-left: 0px;}"),
                              #Floating panel 
                              absolutePanel(id = "controls", style="z-index:400;", class = "panel panel-default", fixed = TRUE,
                                            draggable = TRUE, top = 75, left = 55, 
                                            width = 330, height = "auto",
                                            
                                            h4("symptoms"),
                                            
                                            selectInput("symptom", "Select symptom", c("Chills",
                                                                                       "Cough", "Diarrhoea",
                                                                                       "Fatigue",
                                                                                       "Headache",
                                                                                       "Loss of smell and taste",
                                                                                       "Muscle ache",
                                                                                       "Nasal congestion",
                                                                                       "Nausea and vomiting",
                                                                                       "Shortness of breath",
                                                                                       "Sore throat",
                                                                                       "Sputum",
                                                                                       "Temperature")
                                            ), 
                                            
                                            plotOutput("frequencies_symptom", height = "130px", width = "100%"), 
                                            
                                            tags$div(id="cite",
                                                     'Data provided by fake.data'
                                            )
                              )))
    )

)

                                            
                                            
server <- function(input, output) {
    
    filtered_data <- reactive({
        fake_data %>% 
            dplyr::filter(Symptom %in% input$symptom)
    })
    
    output$frequencies_symptom <- renderPlot({
      
      plot_freq_country(data = fake_data, start_date = min_date, 
                        end_date = max_date, 
                        title = "Frequency accross Symptoms")
    })
    
    output$map <- renderLeaflet({
        
        leaflet() %>%
            addTiles(urlTemplate = "//{s}.tiles.mapbox.com/v3/jcheng.map-5ebohr46/{z}/{x}/{y}.png",
                     attribution = 'Maps by <a href="http://www.mapbox.com/">Mapbox</a>') %>%
            addMarkers(data = filtered_data(), clusterOptions = markerClusterOptions())
      
        
    })
    
}



# Run the application 
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Then as you observe, this is the bit that is important, I place my output plot in ui:

```
plotOutput("frequencies_symptom", height = "130px", width = "100%"),
```

And then apply the function `plot_freq_country` on the `fake_data`. The plot is exactly like in this picture on the dialogue box.
[image]

The caveat though, is that when I move on different country, on the map, I am hoping the bar plot to update itself as it is updating itself on the SuperZip shiny app in the link provided.

You may need the css file as well and it is at this link: https://github.com/gabrielburcea/stackoverflow_fake_data/blob/master/style.css

Addition of my full code on a more realistic data.

```
  pivot_data$Country <-
    dplyr::recode(
        pivot_data$Country,
        'United States of America' = 'USA',
        'Great Britain' = 'United Kingdom'
    )

pivot_data$Date <- as.Date(pivot_data$'Date.Completed', tz = "Europe/London")
pivot_data$Gender <- as.factor(pivot_data$Gender)
pivot_data$Country <- as.factor(pivot_data$Country)
pivot_data$Location <- as.factor(pivot_data$Location)
pivot_data$Chills <- as.factor(pivot_data$Chills)
pivot_data$Cough  <- as.factor(pivot_data$Cough)
pivot_data$Diarrhoea  <- as.factor(pivot_data$Diarrhoea)
pivot_data$Fatigue  <- as.factor(pivot_data$Fatigue)
pivot_data$Headache   <- as.factor(pivot_data$Headcahe)
pivot_data$loss_smell_taste  <- as.factor(pivot_data$'Loss.of.smell.and.taste')
pivot_data$muscle_ache <- as.factor(pivot_data$'Muscle.Ache')
pivot_data$nasal_congestion <- as.factor(pivot_data$'Nasal.Congestion')
pivot_data$nausea_vomiting  <- as.factor(pivot_data$'Nausea.and.Vomiting')
pivot_data$shortness_breath <- as.factor(pivot_data$'Shortness.of.Breath')
pivot_data$sore_throat <- as.factor(pivot_data$'Sore.Throat')
pivot_data$sputum <- as.factor(pivot_data$Sputum)
pivot_data$temperature  <- as.factor(pivot_data$Temperature)



level_key_chills <-
    c(
        'Yes' = "Chills",
        'No' = "No",
        'Yes' = "Mild",
        'Yes' = "Moderate",
        'Yes' = "Severe"
    )
level_key_cough <-
    c(
        'Yes' = "Cough",
        'No' = "No",
        'Yes' = "Mild",
        'Yes' = "Moderate",
        'Yes' = "Severe"
    )
level_key_diarrhoea <-
    c(
        'No' = "No",
        'Yes' = "Mild",
        'Yes' = "Moderate",
        'Yes' = "Severe"
    )
level_key_fatigue <-
    c(
        'No' = "No",
        'Yes' = "Mild",
        'Yes' = "Moderate",
        'Yes' = "Severe"
    )
level_key_headache <-
    c(
        'No' = "No",
        'Yes' = "Mild",
        'Yes' = "Moderate",
        'Yes' = "Severe",
        'Yes' = "Headcahe"
    )
level_key_loss_smell_taste <-
    c(
        'No' = "Loss of smell and taste",
        'No' = "No",
        'Yes' = "Mild",
        'Yes' = "Moderate",
        'Yes' = "Severe"
    )
level_key_muschle_ache <-
    c(
        'No' = "No",
        'No' = "Muscle Ache",
        'Yes' = "Mild",
        'Yes' = "Moderate",
        'Yes' = "Severe"
    )
level_key_nasal_congestion <-
    c(
        'No' = "No",
        'No' = "Nasal Congestion",
        'Yes' = "Mild",
        'Yes' = "Moderate",
        'Yes' = "Severe"
    )
level_key_nausea_vomiting <-
    c(
        'No' = "No",
        'Yes' = "Nausea and Vomiting",
        'Yes' = "Mild",
        'Yes' = "Moderate",
        'Yes' = "Severe"
    )
level_key_self_diagnosis <-
    c(
        'No' = "None",
        'Yes' = "Mild",
        'Yes' = "Moderate",
        'Yes' = "Severe"
    )
level_key_short_breath <-
    c(
        'No' = "No",
        'No' = "Shortness of Breath",
        'Yes' = "Mild",
        'Yes' = "Moderate",
        'Yes' = "Severe"
    )
level_key_sore_throat <-
    c(
        'No' = "No",
        'No' = "Sore Throat",
        'Yes' = "Mild",
        'Yes' = "Moderate",
        'Yes' = "Severe"
    )
level_key_sputum <-
    c(
        'No' = "No",
        'No' = "Sputum",
        'Yes' = "Mild",
        'Yes' = "Moderate",
        'Yes' = "Severe"
    )
level_key_care_home_worker <-
    c('Yes' = 'Yes',
      'No' = 'No')

level_key_temperature <-
    c('No' = 'No',
      Yes = '37.5-38',
      Yes =  '37.5-38',
      Yes = "38.2-39",
      Yes = '38.1-39',
      Yes = '39.1-41',
      Yes = 'Temperature'
    )


data_not_sev <- pivot_data %>%
    dplyr::mutate(
        Chills = forcats::fct_recode(Chills,!!!level_key_chills),
        Cough = forcats::fct_recode(Cough,!!!level_key_cough),
        Diarrhoea = forcats::fct_recode(Diarrhoea,!!!level_key_diarrhoea),
        Fatigue = forcats::fct_recode(Fatigue,!!!level_key_fatigue),
        Headache = forcats::fct_recode(Headache,!!!level_key_headache),
        'Loss of smell and taste' = forcats::fct_recode(loss_smell_taste,!!!level_key_loss_smell_taste),
        'Muscle ache' = forcats::fct_recode(muscle_ache,!!!level_key_muschle_ache),
        'Nasal congestion' = forcats::fct_recode(nasal_congestion,!!!level_key_nasal_congestion),
        'Nausea and vomiting' = forcats::fct_recode(nausea_vomiting,!!!level_key_nausea_vomiting),
        'Shortness of breath' = forcats::fct_recode(shortness_breath,!!!level_key_short_breath),
        'Sore throat' = forcats::fct_recode(sore_throat,!!!level_key_sore_throat),
        Temperature = forcats::fct_recode(temperature, !!!level_key_temperature),
        Sputum = forcats::fct_recode(Sputum,!!!level_key_sputum), 
    ) %>%
    dplyr::select(
        ID,
        Date,
        Country,
        Location,
        Chills,
        Cough,
        Diarrhoea,
        Fatigue,
        Headache,
        'Loss of smell and taste',
        'Muscle ache',
        'Nasal congestion',
        'Nausea and vomiting',
        'Shortness of breath',
        'Sore throat',
        Sputum,
        Temperature,
        lat,
        lon
    )


gather_divided <- data_not_sev %>%
  tidyr::pivot_longer(cols = 5:17,
                      names_to = "Symptom",
                      values_to = "Severity") %>%
  dplyr::filter(Severity != "No") %>%
  dplyr::group_by(Symptom, Country, Location, lon, lat) %>%
  dplyr::tally() %>%
  dplyr::mutate(Frequency = n/sum(n))

gather_divided$Symptom <- as.character(gather_divided$Symptom)
gather_divided$Country <- as.character(gather_divided$Country)
gather_divided$Location <- as.character(gather_divided$Location)

gather_divided$rownum <- seq.int(nrow(gather_divided))

gather_divided <- data.table(gather_divided)
# Define UI for application that draws a histogram
ui <-  bootstrapPage(
    
    navbarPage(theme = shinytheme("flatly"), header = "", 
               "Symptom Tracker", id = "nav",
               
               tabPanel("Interactive map", 
                        div(class = "outer",
                            tags$head(includeCSS("styles.css")),
                            #tags$head(tags$link(rel = "stylesheet", type = "text/css", href = "style.css")),
                            leafletOutput("map", width = "100%", height = 1000), 
                            tags$style(type = "text/css", ".container-fluid {padding-left:0px;padding-right:0px;}"),
                            tags$style(type = "text/css", ".navbar {margin-bottom: .5px;}"),
                            tags$style(type = "text/css", ".container-fluid .navbar-header .navbar-brand {margin-left: 0px;}"),
                            #Floating panel 
                            absolutePanel(id = "controls", style="z-index:400;", class = "panel panel-default", fixed = TRUE,
                                          draggable = TRUE, top = 75, left = 55, 
                                          width = 330, height = "auto",
                                          
                                          h4("symptoms"),
                                          
                                          selectInput("symptom", "Select symptom", c("Chills",
                                                                                     "Cough", "Diarrhoea",
                                                                                     "Fatigue",
                                                                                     "Headache",
                                                                                     "Loss of smell and taste",
                                                                                     "Muscle ache",
                                                                                     "Nasal congestion",
                                                                                     "Nausea and vomiting",
                                                                                     "Shortness of breath",
                                                                                     "Sore throat",
                                                                                     "Sputum",
                                                                                     "Temperature") 
                                          ),            
                                                      
                                          
                                          plotOutput("barplot"),
                                          
                                          

                                          # absolutePanel(id = "logo", class = "card", bottom = 20, left = 60, width = 80, fixed=TRUE, draggable = FALSE, height = "auto",
                                          #             tags$a(tags$img(src="logo.png",height='40',width='80'))),
                                          # 
                                          # absolutePanel(id = "logo", class = "card", bottom = 20, left = 20, width = 30, fixed=TRUE, draggable = FALSE, height = "auto",
                                          #               actionButton("twitter_share", label = "", icon = icon("twitter"),style='padding:5px',
                                          #                            onclick = sprintf("window.open('%s')", 
                                          #                                              "twitter"))),         
                                          # 
                                          tags$div(id="cite",
                                                   'Data provided by fake.data'
                                          )
                            )))
    )
    
)



server <- function(input, output) {
    
    filtered_data <- reactive({
        gather_divided %>% 
            dplyr::filter(Symptom %in% input$symptom)
      
    })
    
    
    output$frequencies_symptom <- renderPlot({
      plot_freq_country(data = data_not_sev, 
                     start_date = min_date, 
                     end_date = max_date, 
                     title = "Frequency accross Symptoms")
    })
    
    
    
    output$map <- renderLeaflet({
        
        leaflet() %>%
            addTiles(urlTemplate = "//{s}.tiles.mapbox.com/v3/jcheng.map-5ebohr46/{z}/{x}/{y}.png",
                     attribution = 'Maps by <a href="http://www.mapbox.com/">Mapbox</a>') %>%
            addMarkers(data = filtered_data(), clusterOptions = markerClusterOptions())
        
        
    })
 
    
    # When a marker is hovered over... 
    observeEvent(input$mymap_marker_mouseover$id, {
      
      ## when a marker is hovered over...subset data to that country
      filt_dat <- reactive({
        pointer <- input$mymap_marker_mouseover$id
        t <- 0.5
        la <- input$mymap_marker_mouseover$lat
        lo <- input$mymap_marker_mouseover$lng
        
        df <- subset(gather_divided, ((lat-t < la & la < lat+t) & (lon-t < lo & lo < lon+t)))
        df
      })
      
      output$barplot <- renderPlot({
        
        mycountry <- unique(filt_dat()$Country)
        plot <- ggplot2::ggplot(filt_dat(), aes(x = Symptom, y = n, fill = n)) +
          ggplot2::geom_bar(stat = "identity", position = "dodge") +
          ggplot2::scale_fill_viridis_c(option = "magma", direction = -1, breaks = unique(filt_dat()$n)) +
          scale_x_discrete(breaks = unique(filt_dat()$Symptom)) +
          scale_y_continuous(breaks = unique(filt_dat()$n), labels=unique(filt_dat()$n) ) +
          guides(fill = "none") +
          theme_minimal() + labs(fill=NULL, title=mycountry) + coord_flip()
        
        #plotly::ggplotly(plot)
        plot
      })
      
      observeEvent(input$mymap_marker_mouseout$id, {
        leafletProxy("mymap") %>% clearPopups()
      })
      
    })
    
    
    
    
}



# Run the application 
shinyApp(ui, server)
```

and a bit of data which is more realistic is here:
https://github.com/gabrielburcea/stackoverflow_fake_data/blob/master/test.data.csv

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
fake_data <- read_csv("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/gabrielburcea/stackoverflow_fake_data/master/gather_divided.csv")

fake_data <- fake_data %>% mutate(rownum = (1:nrow(fake_data)))

###  Define UI for application that draws a histogram
ui <- bootstrapPage(

  navbarPage(theme = shinytheme("flatly"), header = "",
             "Symptom Tracker", id = "nav",

             tabPanel("Interactive map",
                      div(class = "outer",
                          #tags$head(includeCSS("style3.css")),

                          tags$head(tags$link(rel = "stylesheet", type = "text/css", href = "style3.css")),

                          leafletOutput("mymap", width = "100%", height = 1000),

                          tags$style(type = "text/css", ".container-fluid {padding-left:0px;padding-right:0px;}"),
                          tags$style(type = "text/css", ".navbar {margin-bottom: .5px;}"),
                          tags$style(type = "text/css", ".container-fluid .navbar-header .navbar-brand {margin-left: 0px;}"),
                          #Floating panel
                          absolutePanel(id = "controls", style="z-index:400;", class = "panel panel-default", fixed = TRUE,
                                        draggable = TRUE, top = 75, left = 55,
                                        width = 330, height = "auto",

                                        h4("symptoms"),

                                        selectInput("symptom", "Select symptom", c("Chills",
                                                                                   "Cough", "Diarrhoea",
                                                                                   "Fatigue",
                                                                                   "Headache",
                                                                                   "Loss of smell and taste",
                                                                                   "Muscle ache",
                                                                                   "Nasal congestion",
                                                                                   "Nausea and vomiting",
                                                                                   "Shortness of breath",
                                                                                   "Sore throat",
                                                                                   "Sputum",
                                                                                   "Temperature")
                                        ),
                                        tags$div(id="cite",
                                                 'Data provided by fake.data'
                                        ),
                                        plotOutput("barplot")

                          )))
  )

)

server <- function(input, output, session) {

  filtered_data <- reactive({
    fake_data %>%
      dplyr::filter(Symptom %in% input$symptom)
  })
 
  output$mymap <- renderLeaflet({
    leaflet() %>%
      addTiles(urlTemplate = "//{s}.tiles.mapbox.com/v3/jcheng.map-5ebohr46/{z}/{x}/{y}.png",
               attribution = 'Maps by <a href="http://www.mapbox.com/">Mapbox</a>') %>%
      addMarkers(data = filtered_data(), clusterOptions = markerClusterOptions(), layerId = filtered_data()$rownum) 
  })
  
  # When a marker is hovered over... 
  observeEvent(input$mymap_marker_mouseover$id, {

    ## when a marker is hovered over...subset data to that country
    filtered_data2 <- reactive({
      pointer <- input$mymap_marker_mouseover$id
      t <- 0.5
      la <- input$mymap_marker_mouseover$lat
      lo <- input$mymap_marker_mouseover$lng

      df <- subset(fake_data, ((lat-t < la & la < lat+t) & (lon-t < lo & lo < lon+t)))
      df
    })
    
    output$barplot <- renderPlot({

      mycountry <- unique(filtered_data2()$Country)
      plot <- ggplot2::ggplot(filtered_data2(), aes(x = Symptom, y = n, fill = n)) +
        ggplot2::geom_bar(stat = "identity", position = "dodge") +
        ggplot2::scale_fill_viridis_c(option = "magma", direction = -1, breaks = unique(filtered_data2()$n)) +
        scale_x_discrete(breaks = unique(filtered_data2()$Symptom)) +
        scale_y_continuous(breaks = unique(filtered_data2()$n), labels=unique(filtered_data2()$n) ) +
        # theme(legend.position = "right") +
        guides(fill = "none") +
        theme_minimal() + labs(fill=NULL, title=mycountry) + coord_flip()

      #plotly::ggplotly(plot)
      plot
    })
    
    observeEvent(input$mymap_marker_mouseout$id, {
      leafletProxy("mymap") %>% clearPopups()
    })
    
  })

}

# Run the application
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

You will get this output (please modify style3.css to your styles.css):

[image: output]

Comment: Just assigning a row number to be used by layerId later.

Comment: I get this error, but applied to different, real dataset though '''Error: Problem with `mutate()` input `rnum`.
x Input `rnum` can't be recycled to size 1.
ℹ Input `rnum` is `(1:nrow(gather_divided))`.
ℹ Input `rnum` must be size 1, not 45956.
ℹ The error occured in group 1: Symptom = "Chills", Country = "Afganistan", Location = "Jalal Abad", lon = 72.98149.'''

Comment: In that case, just remove that rownum, and define your own row number in the data frame fake_data. It should go from 1 to number of rows in your data frame.

Comment: interesting enough, it is working on fake data but not on real data ... not sure why. Is this because it has more data?

Comment: Yes it depends on the data size. If it is large, you need to switch from data frames to data.table for faster reaction.

Comment: hmm, I will add another code with real data and whole processing. Maybe you'll discover the problem?Thus I will updated it

Comment: Added the full code. Not sure why I do not get the same as yours.

Comment: Please make sure that you do not have any variables with "." in them.  Also, you are missing layerId in `addMarkers`. You need to define `layerId` in `output$map`, inside `addMarkers()`, and tie it to rows in the dataframe.  See my answer on how it was done.

Comment: it seems I do not get any plots, I've waited for several ours and no bar plots. Is it probably a better way to process data outside of renderPlot? Because I feel that is that slows down really badly my bar plotting. Would you please try it on the test dataset? I wish I would know how you are dealing with it?

Comment: so, apparently, this is working but very very slow. Thank you so much! Additionally is there a way to get the frequency axis with clear numbers? I will mark this as an answer. And will post the frequency axis question into another one. Thank you a lot!